# SQL how to retrieve last ordered 2 of the listed products from all customers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

This is my current query:

```
SELECT 
    c.name, c.email, c.phone, sol.description, so.orderDate 
FROM 
    SalesOrderLine sol
JOIN 
    SalesOrder so ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id
JOIN 
    Customer c ON so.customerID = c.id
WHERE 
    (orderDate >= '2020-05-01' AND orderDate <= '2020-09-09')
    AND (description LIKE '%Seed Mix%' OR description LIKE '%Sesame Seeds (Natural)%')
ORDER BY 
    c.name
```

**Goal**

I am aiming to retrieve where product is seed mix or sesame seeds. And between two dates. But only show the most recent date ordered for each customer for both of the products.

Output:

[image]

**Question**

How can I get earliest date they have ordered for both the 1st or 2nd product mentioned in the query?

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: Why customername2 has 3 records for same date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT c.name, c.email, c.phone, sol.description, so.orderDate,
        RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY c.id, sol.product_id ORDER BY so.orderDate DESC) rn
    FROM SalesOrderLine sol
    JOIN SalesOrder so ON sol.salesOrderID = so.id
    JOIN Customer c ON so.customerID = c.id
    WHERE 
        orderDate >= '20200501' 
        AND orderDate <= '20200909'
        AND (description LIKE '%Seed Mix%' OR description LIKE '%Sesame Seeds (Natural)%')
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY name
```

Note: it seems like you have exact matches on the `description`. If so, it is more efficient to use equality checks rather than pattern matches. So:

```
AND description IN ('Seed Mix', 'Sesame Seeds (Natural)')
```

Comment: Use `order by name` without `c.`

Comment: @LV98: ok, I adapted the query. I assumed that you have a column called `product_id` in SaleOrderLine that identifies a product. You might need to review that.